# formatoptions for hybrid (short markup + long paragraphs) content

Tags: autocmd, formatting, filetype, filetype-tex, wrapping

I am trying to write my PhD thesis in vim using LaTeX

So the documents will have two distinct types of content - markups that are relatively short, and paragraph text that is rather long.

```
\begin{some environment}
 Long content here (Lorem  ipsum dolor ......
.........
\end{end enviroment}
```

Since the drafts will involve a lot of edits, in order to keep my writing comprehensible for the text, I had set an `autocmd` to set `formatoptions=at` and `textwidth=110` based on `filetype=tex` so that vim shall insert linebreaks appropriately and reformat documents on the fly upon delete/edit cycles.

The problem is that these reformats happen for the markup text also. For example, if I edit just the markup, the autoformatting kicks in, realigning linebreaks to satisfy the textwidth setting. Similarly, comment lines are also mangled up by the on-the-fly reformatting.

How do I set up the `formatoptions` in my vimrc in such a way that these autocommands fire only for long paragraphs and leaves short texts and comments unchanged.

Comment: You might like to take a look at [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/649/343) which solves the same problem but in Markdown files.

Comment: I think the answer by Hotschke should suffice, but I would also like to add that you should reconsider hardwrapping in general. When working with LaTeX documents, it is much easier to see the difference between different versions of the manuscript if you instead use either a sentence or a paragraph per line and allow long lines. In this case, you should keep `set textwidth=0` and `set wrap`. If you insist on hardwrapping, I would recommend to use `textwidth=80` (or smaller) to make sure that the content fits in standard terminals.

Comment: There is another recommendation for formatting source code:  http://dustycloud.org/blog/vcs-friendly-patchable-document-line-wrapping/. There has already been a question regarding this style: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6004/text-formatting-cvs-friendly. I have pointed out a possibility for automation https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14227/1292. However, I do it more or less manually. The easier style is using softwrapping. I am not sure whether Karl is necessarily right that diffs are easier to read e.g. git diff in the terminal for a long paragraph.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, In normal mode, I tend to use ```par``` to wrap only long lines using ```gq```. But this is a manual process. Can this be triggered in insert mode automatically with vimtex?

Comment: @Hotschke I agree that style is more pleasant, but I've found the "one line per sentence" to work quite well with wrapping in a normal Vim window. And more importantly, it solves the issue of diffing various versions, and it is easy to get coworkers to use the same style. I think the latter point is the most difficult part about the "improved" style.

Comment: @Krishna I strongly recommend that you do not do any autoformatting. If you add `let g:vimtex_format_enabled = 1`, then you can get an improved formatter with `gq` for LaTeX and manually format paragraphs with e.g. `gqip`.

Note: All of this is clearly very subjective, and even though I propose some personal opinions, you are of course allowed to do whatever you want! But I do think `textwidth=80` (or smaller) is good advice, as well as what I've written about diff-friendly styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [latexindent.pl](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent)

I cannot answer your question regarding setting [`formatoptions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27) and [`textwidth`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27) differently for different parts of the same file.

However, I would recommend to use a dedicated tool to format LaTeX code such as  `latexindent.pl`.

This tool has to be configured via a `config.yaml` file, e.g.

```
modifyLineBreaks:
    textWrapOptions:
       columns: 110
```

Invocation on commandline would be:

```
$ latexindent.pl -m input.tex -o output.tex -l config.yaml
```

You can also call this on the current file within vim with

`:!latexindent.pl -w -m % -l config.yaml`.

`latexindent.pl` can also read from STDIN and output to STDOUT and therefore can be used as a [filter](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#filter) in vim.

You could also assign this command to [`formatprg`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27).

See the vim plugin https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat for a setup of latexindent.pl.

#### [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)

An alternative to `latexindent.pl` is the vim plugin `vimtex` which offers format capabilities by a custom [`formatexpr`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatexpr%27).
This is not enabled by default:

```
*g:vimtex_format_enabled*
  If enabled, |vimtex| uses a custom |formatexpr| that should handle inline
  comments. That is, if it is enabled, comments at end of lines will not be
  joined with the |gq| command.

  Default value: 0
```

If you need to customize how your code is formatted, `latexindent.pl` offers more possibilities.